# Calculate row count when facing SPOOL space issue

Tags: sql, performance, teradata

```
SEL COUNT(*) FROM DATABASE_A.QF
```

Count = 37,011,480

```
SEL COUNT(*) FROM DATABASE_A_INC.QFA
```

Count = 368,454

**Query 1**

```
DELETE A
FROM 
    DATABASE_A.QF A,
    DATABASE_A_INC.QFA B
WHERE
    A.Q_NUM = B.Q_NUM
AND
    A.ID = B.ID 
AND 
    A.LOCATION_ID=1;
```

The above DELETE query runs into SPOOL space issue.

So I rewrote it in another form.

**Query 2**

```
DELETE FROM DATABASE_A.QF  A WHERE (Q_NUM,ID) IN 
(SELECT Q_NUM,ID FROM DATABASE_A_INC.QFA B) 
AND LOCATION_ID=1;
```

368454 rows processed.
DELETE Command Complete

My questions:

1. Are query 1 and 2 logically the same? Are they deleting the same records?
2. How do I verify the count from Query 1 without running into a SPOOL
   space issue? I have tried a general COUNT function. I tried increasing spool space to a certain extent.
3. Is there a better way to check the count for Query 1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DELETE query performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40626973/delete-query-performance)

Comment: It's not at all duplicate. Entirely different question.

Answer (score 0):

The queries are logically the same, yes. My guess is the reason for your SPOOL space issue is that you are listing your tables with commas instead of joining them. Try counting query 1 like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM DATABASE_A.QF A
INNER JOIN DATABASE_A_INC.QFA B ON A.Q_NUM = B.Q_NUM
WHERE A.ID = B.ID
AND A.LOCATION_ID=1;
```

Comment: I'll run and revert back. Thanks !

Comment: Let me know what you find. There are other options as well!

Comment: I get `Exception criteria exceeded:   CPU Time.` for `select count`